# Manipulating woocommerce price

Tags: php, wordpress

I extra fields that contain extra data for product. I want to add kilograms. Then i get the value from the kilograms field and multiply it with unit price. Is there any easy way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a plugin should be the way to go.

A free one: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-price-calculator/

Premium one: https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/

Cheers

Comment: I have custom fields generated by another plugin, so i have to do it in code. So i don't think this is a good option. Do you mabye know a filter or something that could do that trick ? In which could insert the field that is generated inside my product meta data ?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but it requires lots of development work and you should be fluent in JS because I imagine you want the price to change in real time as you change units in front end.

Comment: Looking at the plugin, there is no option to obtain current object price.